# How to find the limit of a composite function?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

I think there's a law something like this $\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))= f(\lim_{x\to a} g(x))$
but it has two conditions:

1. Limit of g(x) at $a$ should exist.
2. $f(x)$ should be continuous at $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$.

In the picture, I don't think $f(x)$ is continuous so how would I find this limit?

There's an answer given in the book but I don't understand it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : The answers already given are understood by me, but I am not sure if they are correct, so if you could give a specific credible answer, I'd appreciate that.
Thanks!

Comment: So is it something like the function should be only continuous at that particular point and it doen't matter if the fucntion in general has discontinuities?

Comment: There is another law as well which doesn't need continuity. If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) =b$ and $g(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ and $\lim_{x\to b} f(x) =L$ then $\lim_{x\to a} f(g(x)) =L$. Hope this helps for your scenario.

Comment: On a further look at your question it appears that a version on the law (mentioned in previous comment) applicable to one sided limits is required. Note here that $a=2,b=1$ and further $g(x) >b$ as $x\to a$ and hence one should look at the right hand side limit of $f(x) $ at $b$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Why the right side and why not left? Since $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$ doesn't exist as the left and right sided limits are not equal, why would we choose the right sided limit over the left sided?

Comment: Because $g(x) $ is taking values greater than $b$ which essentially means that $g(x) \to b^+$.

Comment: But g(x) has equal two sided limit, even if we approach it from the left or values lesser than b, we get th same values. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Okay, I think I understand this now. Since $g(x) when x =b$ > $\lim_{x\to b} g(x)$, we see values from the positive side for f(x) $(b^+)$. Am i right? @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Yes your last comment is correct.

Comment: Alternative approach: Consider small $~\epsilon,~$ say $~\epsilon = 1/1000.~$  Then, evaluate both $~f(g(2-\epsilon))~$ and $~f(g(2+\epsilon)).$

Comment: @user2661923 But isn't that just the composite of actual function values? That is f(g(2-e)) = f(g(2)) = f(3)= 3? Since e is so small, we can just approximate the function values right? Can we find the limit like this?

Comment: The point is to expand your intuition.  That is, when you look at the graph of $~g(x),~$ you see that when $~x~$ approaches $~2~$ both from below and from above, that in both cases, $~g(x) > 1.~$  Then, you are supposed to look at the graph of $~f(x)~$ and intuit that therefore, when $~x~$ approaches $~2~$ both from below and from above, that $~f(g(x)) = 3.~$  Therefore, $~\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2} f(g(x)) = 3.~$  The idea was to work on your intuition, so that the result *makes sense*.

Comment: Thanks for this @user2661923, but I still don't understand how actual functions compare with limits and how their values are connected. :(

Comment: Perhaps your math teacher can help.

Comment: Well, I am self studying so I got no choice. Anyway, thanks for trying. @user2661923

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember I wrote the law you mentioned on blackboard with chalk many years ago.

Let us define the restricted function $\tilde f:[1,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $\tilde f(x)=3.$ Then $\tilde f$ is
continuous and $(f\circ g)(x)=(\tilde f\circ g)(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Applying the law, we have
$$\lim_{x\to 2} f(g(x))=\lim_{x\to 2} \tilde{f}(g(x))=\tilde{f}(\,\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)\,)=\tilde{f}(1)=3.
$$